# C# implementation of RemoteWebDriver fails to install Chrome extension

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This ticket is related to ticket [1578 for Selenium](https://github.com/seleniumhq/selenium/issues/1578) , but my issue is with Chrome and not Firefox as in that ticket.

Installing and configuring an extension works when using a local driver. Doing the same using the C# implementation of RemoteWebDriver does not. Tested this with Chrome.

In my test case, the remote execution was done against SauceLabs. Contacted their support and they verified that installing extensions via RemoteWebDriver works in the JAVA implementation, but fails using the C# implementation.

To quote from their support ticket:

"I tried this myself and I was running into issues on my own end, so this may be a flaw with the C# Selenium bindings with RemoteWebDriver."

My code:

```
private IWebDriver GetSauceLabsDriver(){
    var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddExtensions(outPutDirectory + @"\3.1.3_0.crx");
    //DesiredCapabilities caps = (DesiredCapabilities)options.ToCapabilities();
    var caps = new DesiredCapabilities();
    caps.SetCapability(ChromeOptions.Capability, options.Extensions[0]);
    caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
    caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "53.0");
    caps.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows 10");
    caps.SetCapability("deviceName", "");
    caps.SetCapability("deviceOrientation", "");
    caps.SetCapability("username", "kin");
    caps.SetCapability("accessKey", "9cd6-438e-a9635b70953d");
    caps.SetCapability("name", TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name);

    return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), caps,
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
}
```

Comment: What do you mean fails in c#?? Need to share exception as well if occurred

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a common mistake made by users of the .NET bindings. You should almost never be using the `DesiredCapabilities` class directly in your code. Rather, you should almost exclusively be using the `ChromeOptions` class to set all of the options before instantiaung the driver, and use the `.ToCapabilitied()` method to convert it to an `ICapabilities` object that can be used with the `RemoteWebDriver` constructor. In your specific case, that would look like this:

```
private IWebDriver GetSauceLabsDriver()
{
    var outPutDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location);
    ChromeOptions options = new ChromeOptions();
    options.AddExtensions(outPutDirectory + @"\3.1.3_0.

    // Add capabilities that belong at the top
    // level of the capabilities object as opposed
    // to part of the chromeOptions capability. Note
    // that setting the browser name is entirely 
    // redundant and thus is not done. Likewise,
    // deviceName and deviceOrientation are 
    options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Version, "53.0", true);
    options.AddAdditionalCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, "Windows 10", true);
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("username", "kin", true);
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("accessKey", "9cd6-438e-a9635b70953d", true);
    options.AddAdditionalCapability("name", TestContext.CurrentContext.Test.Name, true);

    return new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ondemand.saucelabs.com:80/wd/hub"), options.ToCapabilities(),
        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(600));
}
```

Comment: Thanks Jim, worked flawlessly and thanks for the corrections and your input on cleaning up redundant code. Just to clarify that I understand. Don't use DesiredCapabilities with Chrome, but rather ChromeOptions. This doesn't apply to other drivers, right? The only update that  I had to make was rather than using SetAdditionalCapability(), I had to use AddAdditionalCapability() as ChromeOptions didn't have SetAdditionalCapability() method.

Comment: The code was written from memory, without access to an IDE. I've edited my answer to use the correct method name. To answer your question, the only driver to not use the appropriate Options class with is Firefox. Starting with 3.0, you'll use a `FirefoxOptions` class for it too.